# Why JavaScript deconstructing not working inline

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In hash color function, I assign title and rating by deconstructing them from another object but instead it assign the full color object, and if I break the code into two lines (first deconstructing and assign(reconstructing) then it works fine. Please explain the logic running behind this.

```
const colors = [{
    id: '-xekare',
    title: "rad red",
    rating: 3
}, {
    id: '-jbwsof',
    title: "big blue",
    rating: 2
}, {
    id: '-prigbj',
    title: "grizzly grey",
    rating: 5
}, {
    id: '-ryhbhsl',
    title: "banana",
    rating: 1
}]

hashcolor=colors.reduce((hash,color)=>{
    hash[color.id]={title,rating}=color
    return hash
},[])

console.log(hashcolor);
```

Comment: Assignment `a = (b = c)` always assigns the value of `c` to `a`, no matter what `b` is.

Comment: thanks now i understand , but i am still curious to know how they implement this ,i know they are creating a variable just by matching with names but not able to understand everything running behind this.Can you help me to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're destructuring, you're creating (or assigning to) *individual variables* - you're not creating a new object, so `hash[color.id] = { title, rating }` doesn't actually work. You could write (or copy) a `pick` function that accomplishes that, but in this case, you could just destructure in the arguments instead.

You should also probably use an object as the accumulator, rather than an array:

```js
const colors = [{
  id: '-xekare',
  title: "rad red",
  rating: 3
}, {
  id: '-jbwsof',
  title: "big blue",
  rating: 2
}, {
  id: '-prigbj',
  title: "grizzly grey",
  rating: 5
}, {
  id: '-ryhbhsl',
  title: "banana",
  rating: 1
}]

const hashcolor = colors.reduce((hash, { id, title, rating }) => {
  hash[id] = { title, rating };
  return hash;
}, {})

console.log(hashcolor);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it looks the same, there are actually 2 phases to a creation of an object from destructured properties:

1. [Destructure and assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) the properties to variables (or consts) - `const { title, rating } = color`.
2. Use [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) to create the object `const obj = { title, rating }`.

In your case you can move the destructuring phase to the function call:

```js
const colors = [{"id":"-xekare","title":"rad red","rating":3},{"id":"-jbwsof","title":"big blue","rating":2},{"id":"-prigbj","title":"grizzly grey","rating":5},{"id":"-ryhbhsl","title":"banana","rating":1}]

const hashcolor = colors.reduce((hash, { id, title, rating }) => {
  hash[id] = { title, rating }
  return hash
}, {})

console.log(hashcolor);
```

And you can also use [object rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring), to create the object:

```js
const colors = [{"id":"-xekare","title":"rad red","rating":3},{"id":"-jbwsof","title":"big blue","rating":2},{"id":"-prigbj","title":"grizzly grey","rating":5},{"id":"-ryhbhsl","title":"banana","rating":1}]

const hashcolor = colors.reduce((hash, { id, ...newColor }) => {
  hash[id] = newColor
  return hash
}, {})

console.log(hashcolor);
```